# How do I fill in the holes in an image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am having some difficulty in filling the internal holes of an image, your help would be greatly appreciated.

In terms of scatter :

```
mlist_0 = movelist_porous[0]
rx = np.round(mlist_0[:,0])
ry = np.round(mlist_0[:,1])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(12,8))
axs.scatter(mlist_0[:,0], mlist_0[:,1], color='black')
plt.axis('off')
# plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

In terms of plot :

```
mlist_0 = movelist_porous[0]
rx = np.round(mlist_0[:,0])
ry = np.round(mlist_0[:,1])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(12,8))
axs.plot(mlist_0[:,0], mlist_0[:,1], color='black')
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to have an outcome like this:

[image]

The holes are filled with one colour (black) and the surrounding contour another colour (white), however, I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: Maybe you want to upload the starting image? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 5):

Here you go, starting with the image from plot.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Reading the image saved from plot
image = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

# Coversion to grayscale, inversion, edge detection
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)

# Find the contours. The first two largest contours are for the outer contour
# So, taking the rest of the contours for inner contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[2:]

# Filling the inner contours with black color
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), -1)

# Displaying the result
cv2.imshow("Contour", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output from the code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really useful in terms of automatically filling this holes, as this needs to be repeated in many layers and it would be impossible and stupid of me to manually fill in colours one by one.

Comment: Hi Amras, I think you left out the part where the background has to be black in colour also. Possible to do that?

Comment: @EzerSin One, very naive, way of doing that is performing _flood filling_ on the background by selecting a point inside the "background blob".

Answer (score 2):

If you can, use a Jupyter Notebook with matplotlib.

Starting from the plot I suggest you to use thresholding to get rid of the noise around the line.

```
im = cv2.imread('Fpeck.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
threshold = 127
apply_val = 255
ret, th = cv2.threshold(im, threshold, apply_val, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

If you check the same area of the original and thresholded image you can see the improvement (here is a bit too small, maybe):

[image]

Show the images side by side using this code:

```
original_vs_thresholded = np.concatenate([im[160:200,0:40], th[160:200,0:40]], axis=1)
```

After that find the contours on the thresholded image using cv2.RETR_TREE as retrieval mode, see https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

If you print `hierarchy` you can see the contours and the nesting, it contains a list of index where:

- column (a) is the index of the next element at the same level
- column (b) is the index of the previous element at the same level
- column (c) is the index of the child contour
- column (d) is the index of the parent contour

This is the `hierarchy`:

```
#=>    a  b  c  d
#=>  [-1 -1  1 -1] <- boundary of the image
#=>  [-1 -1  2  0] <- bigger oval, external of the line
#=>  [-1 -1  3  1] <- bigger oval, internal of the line
#=>  [ 5 -1  4  2] <- shape1, external of the line
#=>  [-1 -1 -1  3] <- shape1, internal of the line
#=>  [ 7  3  6  2] <- and so on ...
#=>  [-1 -1 -1  5]
#=>  [ 9  5  8  2]
#=>  [-1 -1 -1  7]
#=>  [11  7 10  2]
#=>  [-1 -1 -1  9]
#=>  [13  9 12  2]
#=>  [-1 -1 -1 11]
#=>  [-1 11 14  2]
#=>  [-1 -1 -1 13]
```

---

For example `hierarchy[0][5]` has values `[ 7  3  6  2]` and corresponds to `contours[5]`.

**Hope this gives you a basic understanding on how to pick the proper contour for building the final result.**

For example collecting the indexes of contours where `hierarchy[0][0] == -1` or `hierarchy[0][3] == 2`.

---

You can plot the sequence of the contour drawing using this code on a notebook:

```
im_cnt_th = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
for n, contour in enumerate(contours):
    color = tuple(int(n) for n in np.random.randint(256, size=3))
    print(color)
    cv2.drawContours(im_cnt_th, [contour], -1, color, cv2.FILLED)
    print(f'index: {n} - hyerarchy: {hierarchy[0][n]}')
    plt.imshow(im_cnt_th[:,:,::-1])
    plt.show()
```

This is the result you should get (**see the overlapping of inner to outer contours**):

[image]

---

## Finally

For the required result, find the inner shape indexes:

```
inner_shapes_indexes = [ idx for idx, h in enumerate(hierarchy[0]) if h[3] == 2] # parent contour is indexed 2 in hierarchy
```

Then, build a black image, plot in white the oval, plot in black the inner shapes:

```
new_im = np.zeros_like(im)
cv2.drawContours(new_im, [contours[1]], -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)
for idx in inner_shapes_indexes:
    cv2.drawContours(new_im, [contours[idx]], -1, 0, cv2.FILLED)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That is such a good answer. This hierarchy helps in terms of splitting into domains.

Comment: Yes, hierarchy helps a lot. I added a possible way to get the final result using it. But it is possible to add some logic to automate the process for similar cases.